# convert msyql Largebinary output to csv

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, csv

I have a MySQL database

```
class Dataset(db.Model):
    data = db.Column(db.LargeBinary)
```

I have saved a CSV in the database and I would like to retrieve the CSV and read in Pandas. When I retrieve the data  as an SQL query I get Byte data
I have a database that uses flask sql_alchemy, the  class looks like this:
class Dataset(db.Model):
    data = db.Column(db.LargeBinary)
on the database, i have saved a csv as a file,
i want to retrieve the csv and read it in pandas: when i query the database:
file_data = Dataset.query.get(1)
file_data.data returns byte data instead of the csv that looks like:

b'PK\x03\x04\x14\x00\x06\x00\x08\x00\x00\x00!\x00b\xee\x9dh^\x01\x00\x00\x90\x04\x00\x00\x13\x00\x08\x02[Content_Types].xml \xa2\x04\x02(\xa0\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00
I have tried converting the file to strings using common encoding such as utf-8,latin1 and so on. I get the folowing error:
'utf-8' codec can't decode bytes in position 15-16: invalid continuation byte

Comment: Could you explain your code a bit more? It is a little unclear...

Answer (score 1):

I actually solved it, I just used:
pd.read_csv(BytesIO(file_data.data))

Comment: I was searching for the answer for almost a day and finally this simple answer helped me!